# Architecture, EF Core 8 and large SQL queries best practice question

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework-core, architecture, software-design

I have a couple of large SQL scripts, but one particular in general which I would like to use as a stored procedure (but I dont since I am not the biggest fan of stored procedures for this kind of query).

My question isnt about the actuall script, but how I should in "best practice" handle a big SQL query which I need to run as RawSql with EF Core. The script takes some parameters and so on.

Should I:

- Store the script in a .sql file in the project and use some kind of `Regex.Replace` for the parameters in the actual content of the file?
- Should I just have a class with SQL scripts which takes in parameters and uses the `$"select * from x where column = '{myParameter}'`"?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards Max

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Currently I just go straight at a PostgresSQL instance, but will use something like postgres-operator, if that counts as a DBMS

Comment: Neither, use proper parameterization like `where column = @myParameter`. See linked answer (but using `NpgsqlParameter` not `SqlParameter`)